# Constructing an isomorphism between two finite fields of order 25.

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

The fields in question are
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{F}_5[x]/(x^2+x+1),\ \mathbb{F}_5(\sqrt{2}).
\end{equation*}
I know that there's an isomorphism between the above fields as they are finite fields of the same order. My idea was to find a generator of the group of units of each field, and construct an isomorphism by mapping one generator to the other.

I found that $x+2$ generates $(\mathbb{F}_5[x]/(x^2+x+1))^{\times}$ and $1+\sqrt{2}$ generates $\mathbb{F}_5(\sqrt{2})^{\times}.$ Then, calling the map $\varphi$, I send $x+2$ to $1+\sqrt{2}$ which gives, after rearranging, $\varphi(x)=\sqrt{2}+4$ where I also used that any isomorphism shall fix the base field $\mathbb{F}_5$. The problem is that the map
\begin{align*}
\varphi:&\mathbb{F}_5[x]/(x^2+x+1)\longrightarrow \mathbb{F}_5(\sqrt{2})\\
&a+bx \mapsto a+4b+b\sqrt{2}
\end{align*}
doesn't satisfy $\varphi(fg)=\varphi(f)\varphi(g)$ for all $f,g \in \mathbb{F}_5[x]/(x^2+x+1).$ Is this down to the general approach being incorrect?

Comment: Hint: In $\mathbb{F}_5,$ $$x^2+x+1=(x-2)^2+2$$

Comment: Another hint: the discriminator of $x^2+x+1$ is just $1-4=-3=2$ in $\Bbb F_5$.

Comment: What other said. Adjoining a root of $x^2+x+1$ (a root of unity of order three) gives $\sqrt{-3}$ and in this field $-3=2$, so you have $\sqrt2$. With [very little extra work](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3050727/11619) you can construct more root of unity familiar from the complex domain :-)

Comment: So as $\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$ is a root of $x^2+x+1$, we find $$\mathbb{F}_5/(x^2+x+1)\cong \mathbb{F}_5(\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2})=\mathbb{F}_5(\sqrt{-3})=\mathbb{F}_5(\sqrt{2})$$ because $-3=2 \in \mathbb{F}_5$. To go from $\mathbb{F}_5/(x^2+x+1)$ to $\mathbb{F}_5(\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2})$, we just evaluate the polynomial elements of the former field at $\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$. Does this give the desired isomorphism?

Comment: Correct, @carraig! I would like to encourage you to write that down as an answer. That way you get more feedback on the details (and the question off the list of unanswered ones).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We notice that $\omega$, a primitive third root of unity, has as minimum polynomial $f(x)=x^2+x+1 \in \mathbb{F}_5[x]$. As $\omega=\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2},$ this gives the following isomorphism $\varphi:$
\begin{align*}
\varphi: \mathbb{F}_5[x]/(x^2+x+1) &\longrightarrow \mathbb{F}_5(\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2})\\
g(x)&\longmapsto g(\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}).
\end{align*}
However, $-3=2 \in \mathbb{F}_5$ and $\mathbb{F}_5(\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2})=\mathbb{F}_5(\sqrt{-3})$ so
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{F}_5[x]/(x^2+x+1) \cong \mathbb{F}_5(\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}) = \mathbb{F}_5(\sqrt{2}).
\end{equation*}