# Order of elements in the multiplicative group of the finite field extension

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field, cyclic-groups

Given the field extension $\mathbb{F}_5(\sqrt2)$, it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_{5^2}$ and the group $\mathbb{F}_{5^2}^{*}$ is cyclic of degree 24 so the elements in it above can be of order $\{2,3,4,6,8,12\}$. How can I calculate the orders of $1 - \sqrt{2}$, $3 - \sqrt2$ in $\mathbb{F}_{5}(\sqrt2)^{*}$ without having to go through all the possible power of said elements ?

Comment: You don't need to compute all powers. Let $v=1 - \sqrt2$. Then $v^3=2$ and so $v^6=\cdots$. Let $w=3 - \sqrt2$. Then $w^3=\cdots$.

Comment: @lhf I understand that just by computing the 2nd and 3rd power we could obtain the rest but is there any method that does not require computing any power at all ?

Comment: I don't know, if you are looking for something like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3050929/11619). You see, I'm a fan of ad hoc tricks. Those do not generalize very well :-)

Comment: It’s not a matter of “by computing the 2nd and 3rd power we could obtain the rest”, but of noting the (already known) order of the square and cube. I would also like to express the opinion that you should embrace with joy the idea of doing  pencil-and-paper computations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to compute all powers, only a few.

Let $v=1 - \sqrt2$. Then $v^3=2$ and so $v^6=4=-1$. Therefore, $v$ has order $12$.

Let $w=3 - \sqrt2$. Then $w^3=\sqrt2$ and so $w^{12}=4=-1$. Therefore, $w$ has order $24$.